# jQuery global regex for replace with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

in the following example I am trying to replace all instances of the `newname` variable with `-`,
however `newname` in my example is handled as text, rather than a as variable.

`var newname = 'test';`

`var lastname = $(this).attr('name').replace(/newname/g, "-");`

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 9):

```
var newname = 'test';
var regex = new RegExp(newname,"g")
var lastname = $(this).attr('name').replace(regex, "-");
```

More info:

http://smyck.net/2006/08/11/javascript-dynamic-regular-expresions/
http://fyneworks.blogspot.com/2007/04/dynamic-regular-expressions-in.html