# Raw html conversion with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to convert `<p> ... <code>&amp;lt;div id='asd'&amp;gt;asd&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;</code></p>` to `<p> ... <code><div id='asd'>asd</div></code></p>` with jquery.

In other saying I want to apply using jquery what `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html))` does as in asp.net MVC.

I tried the solutions of similar problems([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784560/how-to-replace-lt-with-and-gt-with-using-jquery), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)), but they aren't enough to solve my problem. There occured two problems; replace doesn't replace all matching as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xC2tu/5/) (I solved this problem with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892307/jquery-global-regex-for-replace-with-variable)); and the converted code  isn't shown as expected in html and browser. Hierarchy of html is destroyed.

for detail:

**The string to be decoded:**

```
<p>fddfg dfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgd  <em>asdasd</em> <strong>cvbncvbn</strong> <code>&amp;lt;div id='asd'&amp;gt;asd&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;</code></p>
```

**Html output after html decode:**

```
<p>
   fddfg dfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgd
   <em>asdasd</em>
   <strong>cvbncvbn</strong>
   <code></code>
</p>
<div id="asd">
   <code>asd</code>
</div>
<p></p>
```

**Browser output after html decode:**

```
fddfg dfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgd asdasd cvbncvbn

asd
```

You can see the problem in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xC2tu/9/) (look at, especially at console):

**Expected or desired browser output:**

```
fddfg dfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgd asdasd cvbncvbn <div id='asd'>asd</div>
```

Why this broken html output comes out and how can I solve this?

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784560/how-to-replace-lt-with-and-gt-with-using-jquery

Comment: I've tried two links you gave, not working? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with another way. I decoded html in server side of Asp.Net MVC using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html)`.

In detail;

**Server side:**

```
var yorumHtml = "<p>fddfg dfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgd  <em>asdasd</em> <strong>cvbncvbn</strong> <code>&amp;lt;div id='asd'&amp;gt;asd&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;</code></p>";

return Json(new { Success = true, YorumHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(yorumHtml)});
```

**Client side javascript (In success of Ajax):**

```
$('span#container').html(response.YorumHtml);
```

**Html output:**

```
<p>
   fddfg dfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgd
   <em>asdasd</em>
   <strong>cvbncvbn</strong>
   <code><div id='asd'>asd</div></code>
</p>
```

**Browser output:**

```
fddfg dfgdfgdfg dfgdfgdfgd asdasd cvbncvbn <div id='asd'>asd</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/U9nVE/2)

```
var str = $('#test').html($('#test').html()).text();

function decode_str(str) {
    pos = str.indexOf('&lt;');
    while (pos >= 0) {
        str = str.replace('&lt;', '<')
        pos = str.indexOf('&lt;');
    }
    pos = str.indexOf('&gt;');
    while (pos >= 0) {
        str = str.replace('&gt;', '>')
        pos = str.indexOf('&gt;');
    }
    return $.trim(str);
}
console.log(decode_str(str));
$('#test').html(decode_str(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you are after: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xC2tu/)

```
var str = $('#code').html();

function decode(value) {
    return String(value)
        .replace(/&amp;quot;/g, '"')
        .replace(/&amp;#39;/g, "'")
        .replace(/&amp;lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&amp;gt;/g, '>')
        .replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
}
$('#code').text(decode(str));
```

Updated to match your new example: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/h7DrY/)